# remove margin for a viewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am struggling for hours to remove the left and right margin. I want to remove the space between the tableView and the border.

[image: Storyborad]

Comment: Double-click on each constraint (on the right panel) & uncheck `Constrain to margins` (or whatever is called in the inspector panel)

Answer (score 1):

1) Delete the 2 constraints you have 'Trailing space' & 'Leading space'.
2) Making sure you click the same view, open up the 'pin' dialog locating on the bottom right of storyboard. Uncheck the box 'constraints to margins' then add 0's on the left and right margins. Click 'Add 2 constraints'. Then you will no longer see the left and right empty margins (leading & trailing) space in your view controller.

In case you don't see any changes just click on 'Resolve Auto layout Issue' icon locating next to 'pin' button to the right and select 'update Frames' under 'Selected Views'. Good luck

[image]